# Binary Representation of Float in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, floating-point

I'm studying Assembly language and its data types and came across `.float`. I declared a `.float` variable named `Float` and assigned it's value as `10.23`. I used GNU assembler v2.28 to assemble it and followed by GNU Linker v2.28 to link the object file to create an executable binary. Here's my program:

```
.data
    HelloWorld:
        .ascii "Hello World!\n"
    ByteLocation:
        .byte 10
    Int32:
        .int 2
    Int16:
        .short 5
    Float:
        .float 10.23
    IntArr:
        .int 3,6,7,8,10

.bss
    .comm LargeBuffer, 1000

.text
    .globl _start
    _start:
        nop    
        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
```

I set a break point using a GDB debugger.

`(gdb) break *_start+1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b1: file 03 VariableDemo.s, line 22.`

And when I looked at the decimal representation and binary representation of `Float`. I found this:

`(gdb) x/1bw 0x0000000000600139
0x600139:   10.2299995
(gdb) x/1tw 0x0000000000600139
0x600139:   01000001001000111010111000010100`

I'm referring [Can anyone explain representation of float in memory?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/215126/224928) to convert the binary representation back to 10.23. Here's my calculation:

first bit = 1 => The floating point is positive.

next 8 bits = 10000010 => Representing a +2 as the multiplier of significand.

next 23 bits = 01000111010111000010100 => Which when converted with negative power of 2 gives 0.278749943

But 0.278749943*2 is not 10.23. So now I 2 questions in mind.

1. Why is 10.23 in text represented as 10.2299995 in memory.
2. Where did my calculation go wrong?

Comment: For 1. read please: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Conversion error, not everything that is "nice" in base 10 is gonna be nice in base 2.
2. The exponent bias is 127 not 128, so that's a `+3` not a `+2`
3. You actually need to use the exponent, so that's `*2^3` not just `*2`
4. You forgot the implicit leading `1` bit, so you need to add `1` to the mantissa, meaning you have `1.278749943*2^3=10.2299995`

Comment: The stored exponent is 130, you claimed that means a +2 but it actually means a +3 because you need to subtract 127 not 128. The linked answer is wrong about that, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (and your computer) is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 0):

The mantissa has an implicit leading 1, so it is always binary 1.xxxxxxx. It is then left-shifted or right-shifted according to the exponent (the exponent is biased rather than a two's complement binary number, so 127 equals zero shift, or 1.xxxxx, 128 represents 1x.xxxx and so on).

Finally the binary is converted to denary for output.